# How to fix MyBB Javascript error

Tags: javascript, mybb

I'm trying add a JS code to my templates but I'm getting that security error:

**A potential security issue was found in the template. Please review your changes or contact the MyBB Group for support.**

Code:

```
//Start navbar toggle fix top bottom
    $(document).on('click', '.toggle_fixing', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#main_navbar').hasClass('navbar-fixed-top')) {
            $('#main_navbar').toggleClass('navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-fixed-top');
            $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
        } else {
            $('#main_navbar').toggleClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
            $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
            if ($('#main_navbar').parent('div').hasClass('container')) $('#main_navbar').children('div').addClass('container').removeClass('container-fluid');
            else if ($('#main_navbar').parent('div').hasClass('container-fluid')) $('#main_navbar').children('div').addClass('container-fluid').removeClass('container');
            FixMegaNavbar(navHeight);
        }
        if ($('#main_navbar').hasClass('navbar-fixed-top')) {$('body').css({'margin-top': $('#main_navbar').height()+'px', 'margin-bottom': ''});}
        else if ($('#main_navbar').hasClass('navbar-fixed-bottom')) {$('body').css({'margin-bottom': $('#main_navbar').height()+'px', 'margin-top': ''});}
    })
    //End navbar toggle fix top bottom

    //Start Fix MegaNavbar on scroll page
    var navHeight = $('#main_navbar').offset().top;
    FixMegaNavbar(navHeight);
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {FixMegaNavbar(navHeight);});


    function FixMegaNavbar(navHeight) {
        if (!$('#main_navbar').hasClass('navbar-fixed-bottom')) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                $('#main_navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top')
                $('body').css({'margin-top': $('#main_navbar').height()+'px'});
                if ($('#main_navbar').parent('div').hasClass('container')) $('#main_navbar').children('div').addClass('container').removeClass('container-fluid');
                else if ($('#main_navbar').parent('div').hasClass('container-fluid')) $('#main_navbar').children('div').addClass('container-fluid').removeClass('container');
            }
            else {
                $('#main_navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
                $('#main_navbar').children('div').addClass('container-fluid').removeClass('container');
                $('body').css({'margin-top': ''});
            }
        }
    }
    //End Fix MegaNavbar on scroll page

    //Next code used to prevent unexpected menu close when using some components (like accordion, tabs, forms, etc), please add the next JavaScript to your page
    $( window ).load(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar .dropdown-menu', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});
    });
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark here, but it may be MyBB disagreeing with how you have your code formatted.

when it contains stuff like this: `{$('body').css`, it may be confusing it as a template variable; eg. `{$header}`.

Try formatting your code in another way, so there's no brackets right next to dollar signs.

Alternatively, it might be worth keeping js out of the templates and keeping it in a js file.

Comment: I added this code to an external file. But it did not work. Some functions are working when I remove this part: //Start Fix MegaNavbar on scroll page var navHeight = $('#main_navbar').offset().top; FixMegaNavbar(navHeight); $(window).bind('scroll', function() {FixMegaNavbar(navHeight);});

Comment: Did the _A potential security issue was found in the template. Please review your changes or contact the MyBB Group for support._ message go away? If so, I'd recommend marking this as answered and creating a new question with the javascript tag. If you open the javascript console, are there any errors?